# How do I add a custom method to a backbone model?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've tried:

```
initialize: function() {
    if (this.get("id") == "modelOfInterest") {

        var func = function() {
           //do some stuff with the model
         }
         _.bind(func, this)

    }
}
```

and

```
initialize: function() {
    if (this.get("id") == "modelOfInterest") {
          var func = function() {
            //do some stuff with the model
          }
          this.on("func", func, this);
     }
}
```

However in both cases:

```
myModelInstance.func(); //object has no method func
```

I'd prefer not to use `_.bindAll()`.

I've edited the code above to show that I am trying to bind func to only one model. The model is initialize when it is added to a collection : all the models fire initialize at the same time and I just want to bind func to one of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any reason not to do the obvious?

```
Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  func: function() {
  },
})
```

Comment: One possible reason is that this model is used in a collection. I only want to give this method to one of the models. In the initialize function I am testing for the model id to see if it is the one I want so I can bind just to that one. If I did what you suggest I would give the function to all the models.

Comment: This works. I think it means my func is attached to all the models in the collection but it doesn't matter so long as I don't bind any event to them.

Answer (score 3):

Assign `func` as a property of your model in your `if` block.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize:function() {
    if (this.get('id') === 1) {
      this.func = function() {
          // your logic here
      };               
      this.on('func',this.func,this);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Even that didn't work though it set me on the right track. I define the function in the model outside of initialize so it belongs to the Model. Then  the this.on('func'... line works. I don't know why this.func inside of initialize is not attaching the function to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods should be declared on a second dictionary within the .extend call:

```
SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){}
},{
  someStaticFunction: function(){
      //do something
  } 
});
```

http://danielarandaochoa.com/backboneexamples/blog/2013/11/13/declaring-static-methods-with-backbone-js/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){},
  someFunction: function(){
      //do something
  } 
});
```

And this:

```
var model = new SomeModel();
model.someFunction();
```